# Cannot boot to Windows 8.1 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, syslinux

**The issue is fixed, I had forgotten to change boot mode and boot priority in BIOS to UEFI and UEFI  First, and also 'Optimize for' from 'other OS' to 'Win8 64bit'**

First of all, sorry if this question has already been answered. There are so many questions of this topic, and I can't read answers of all of them, read some of them but they weren't helpful.

So I installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo laptop alongside Windows 8.1 UEFI (dual boot) and now I cannot boot to Windows 8.1.  :( When I restart, GRUB boot manager asks me the OS to boot from. When I select Ubuntu it just loads fine but when I select Windows 8.1 I get the following error:

```
windows failed to start. a recent hardware or software change might be the cause. to fix the problem:
    1. insert your installation disc and restart your computer.
    2. choose your language settings.
    3. click repair your computer.

File: \Boot\BCD
Status: 0xc00000e
Info: The boot configuration data for your PC is missing or contains errors.
```

I don't have any installation disc can I fix this by booting to Ubuntu? One of my friend  suggested to do:

```
sudo apt-get install syslinux
sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda
```

But I'm afraid to execute those commands as I don't know what they will do. Any advises?

Comment: yeah, those commands look kind of scary. look here, you may need to run boot-repair http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/167115 also, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and finally http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html

Comment: Yes, installing syslinux isn't going to solve this problem as you already have GRUB and it's working or your Ubuntu wouldn't boot either. The problem is definitely with Windows.

Comment: i'm so stupid. i had forgotten to change boot mode and boot priority in BIOS to UEFI and UEFI  First, and also 'Optimize for' from 'other OS' to 'Win8 64bit.. now it works fine. thanks for taking your time to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can Connect to the Internet try Following Code in a new Terminal Window.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

this will install boot-Repair in Ubuntu. after Installed launch it by typing "boot manager" in Bash or Terminal. When window came up, Select Recommended repair.

further information in [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple , this worked for me

insert Ubuntu cd and select try Ubuntu, connect to Internet open terminal ( Ctrl+Alt+T ),

login as root:

```
sudo -i
```

find out your linux disk :

```
fdisk -l
```

mount it:

```
mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
```

Recover:

```
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```